# Excel no me registra la existencia de un form VBA

Tags: excel, formularios, vba, macros, microsoft-office

Yo hice un excel donde hay una macro que debería arrancar apenas se abra el archivo y ocultar la aplicación y mostrar un form, pero me sale un cartel de error 424 se requiere un objeto, luego lo intente de otra manera que se la dejo abajo y me sale que "Userform1.Visible = True" es un tipo de automatización no permitida. Este error no me a dejado continuar con mi proyecto. Ayuda por favor.

```
Sub auto_open ()

Userform1.Visible = True
Application.Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Intenta usando `UserForm1.Show`. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora lo intente pero ahora me dice que se requiere un objeto y eso es raro porque si lo cree al user form y lo escribí bien, pensé que era porque no puse ningún macro, pero aun poniéndolo me sigue fallando ;-;

Comment: Asegúrate de que el nombre del formulario (UserForm1) no lo has cambiado por otro.

Comment: no, es igual el nombre, hay forma de pasar el excel?

Comment: Supongo que podrás subirlo a onedrive o gdrive y compartir el link.

Comment: Buena idea ahi lo paso

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S90EeeAJUvKDeAjUM7R769rlYGnJnLeB/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale, el código de tú modulo déjalo así:

```
Sub algo()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Y en el código de tu userform, en el evento initialize sólo tienes que añadir un 1 a UserForm:

```
Private Sub UserForm1_initialize()
    Aplication.Visible = False
End Sub
```

De todas formas, para que se abra el formulario nada más abrir el fichero excel debes colocar este código en ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Call algo

End Sub
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. :) aunque me paso algo raro, me funcionó, lo cerré, cuando lo abrí me pido que especificara un bloque with... (?

Comment: Vuelve a revisar el código. Eso es porque tienes algún nombre distinto a lo que he puesto yo. Puede que cerrases sin guardar los cambios.

Comment: funcionoooo :)) no me acuerdo que hice pero esta, gracias de nuevo